# Connect a unity Android app with native android app

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

There should be a button in the **unity application** that will launch the **android app**, similarly there should be a button in the **android app** that will let us switch back to the **unity app**.

Please helo me to perform this task , since im a newbie, i dont know how to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use plugins. The same principal works for iOS apps, and Windows Phone beta apps. You can communicate back and forth from within the View and View Controllers into your Unity Apps via plugins.

Here is a good start:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

Comment: thanks for rplying. but how am I going to create a button in unity app ? and i have seen the link, im not sure how to make a plugin..could you please explain in more simple and detailed way on how i could solve this task :( ...plz help